# SQL Server : LIKE comparison returning all results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT LEFT(name, CHARINDEX('</title><style>', name, 1) - 1)
FROM tableA
WHERE name LIKE '%</title><style>%'
```

And the result set includes all records in the table. I have to assume it has to do something with the slash or gt/lt signs but I've never come up against this issue. I have also tested using a variable (`@Searchstr`) instead and had the same result.

Comment: Please show a few example `name` values that you weren't expecting in the result.

Comment: It could be anything, for example `Test Test` is returned for the above query.

Comment: That sounds very strange. To my knowledge the only characters that get special treatment within a `LIKE` clause are `%` and `_`.

Comment: You're certain there's no dangling OR clause way down below in sql-studio?  I've seen that happen where an OR is several lines below and unseen.

Comment: I'm fairly certain CHARINDEX as a function cannot be constrained. It runs as a function call against the expressions given. So essentially it hits the CHARINDEX call in your query and runs it, ending there.

Comment: I have run the above query against some sample data and it returns only records matching the where clause. my sample data included `Test Test` and that was not in the result set. When I have an issue like this it is often because one of my assumptions is wrong... what are your assumptions... is this an over simplified example you have given us?

Comment: Thanks @GB and Phoenix. This is very much an exact example, but I see that Phoenix might have hit on it. So I suppose in this case I could just remove the WHERE clause. I want to remove some data from every cell in the database, so I could just run the update using the LEFT string above on everything without any WHERE constraint, correct?

Comment: This Q is fine, but we cant reproduce the issue so it is hard to diagnose... it is now that we need to start thinking outside the box. the query you have given us works. so it must be something else. Im trying to help you figure out what "something else" might be. I understand what you are trying to achieve and the above query does that for me.

Comment: Thank you all, I believe my source data is probably the issue. Sorry for the time and trouble.

Comment: The problem then lies with this piece of code:

`SET @SQL= 'UPDATE ' + @TableName + ' SET ' + @ColumnName  + ' =  ' +  LEFT(@ColumnName, CHARINDEX(@SearchStr, @ColumnName, 1) - 1)
    EXEC (@SQL)`

When the string doesn't exist in the data then I get this response: 

`Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.`